# Update Artifcatory on AWS AMI: sudo yum update failing with systemctl: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifactory, amazon-ami, systemctl

I'm trying to update jfrog artifactory which is running on an AWS AMI.

The command `sudo yum update` fails with

```
Downloading packages:
jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.4.rpm                                                            32% [=========================-                                                      ]  0.0 B/s |  24 MB  --:--:-- ETA jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.4.rpm                                                            67% [======================================================                          ]  33 MB/s |  50 MB  00:00:00 ETA jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.4.rpm                                                                                                                                                            |  73 MB  00:00:01     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.xncfmC: line 24: systemctl: command not found
Stopping the artifactory service...
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.xncfmC: line 27: systemctl: command not found
error: %pre(jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.4-50404900.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.4-50404900.noarch
  Verifying  : jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.4.4-50404900.noarch                                                                                                                                                    1/2 
jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.15.0-40350.noarch was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.15.0-40350.noarch                                                                                                                                                      2/2 

Failed:
  jfrog-artifactory-oss.noarch 0:4.15.0-40350                                                            jfrog-artifactory-oss.noarch 0:5.4.4-50404900

Complete!
```

Amazon's AWS AMI doesn't come with systemctl.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this or how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

AWS AMI's are based on centos 6ish version. And its using old libraries. systemd commands are supported in centos7 version. I am into similar situation and thinking to get centos7 AMI instead of Amazon AMI